# php js function time interval

Tags: javascript, php

I have this function:

```
<script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
         (function () {
                 $("#randomtext").load("notification.php");
         }), 10000);
</script>
```

it loads what it gets from notification.php to my div with id randomtext every 10 seconds. Is it possible to make it run at the very first time in like 1 second after the page is loaded and then every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you just need to call `.load` after 1 second

```
<script>
    // Run it for the first time after 1 second
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#randomtext").load("notification.php");
    }, 1000);

    // Run it every ten seconds
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
         (function () {
                 $("#randomtext").load("notification.php");
         }), 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: damn it. you made it look easy. Thanks though. I am still beginner in js

Comment: need to wait 10 minutes :y

Comment: Hey there again. I tried your code, mine again, some testing and now for some reason simple $("#randomtext").load("notification.php") doesn't work what the hell. notification.php exists and I checked it with file_exists();

Comment: agh I fixed it somehow. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                    loadNotification();
                    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
                            loadNotification();
                    }, 10000);
            }, 1000);
        });

       function loadNotification() {
              $("#randomtext").load("notification.php");
        }

</script>
```

if you declare **auto_refresh** outside setTimeout, next load call will go in 9 seconds.

Comment: This is very nice too ! Thanks !